# Помогите с кроссбраузерностью иконок

Tags: css, safari, шрифты

Так отображается в хроме,

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v28/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ewrjPiaoEww8AihgqWRJAo.woff) format('woff');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.9;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.jub-icon-mask.icon-huge {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  line-height: 128px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
}

.jub-icon-mask.bg-blue {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .87);
}

i {
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <div class="feature  " style=' ' data-animated-type="">
    <div class="feature-ct">
      <div class="jub-contents      z-depth- shape-square     " style=" ">
        <div class="jub-element jub-element-icon    spacing-bottom-lg">
          <div class="jub-icon-mask icon-huge shape-round bg-blue    z-depth-0 " style=" border-radius: 0%; opacity: 1;">
            <i class="material-icons">cloud_done</i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А так в safari,как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В новых сафари отображается нормально, для старых браузеров используйте код, как указано в [мануале](http://md.gl/icons/#ic_cloud_done):

Вместо:

```
<i class="material-icons">cloud_done</i>
```

Вставьте:

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE2BF;</i>
```

Ваш пример:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v28/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ewrjPiaoEww8AihgqWRJAo.woff) format('woff');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.9;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.jub-icon-mask.icon-huge {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  line-height: 128px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
}

.jub-icon-mask.bg-blue {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .87);
}

i {
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <div class="feature  " style=' ' data-animated-type="">
    <div class="feature-ct">
      <div class="jub-contents      z-depth- shape-square     " style=" ">
        <div class="jub-element jub-element-icon    spacing-bottom-lg">
          <div class="jub-icon-mask icon-huge shape-round bg-blue    z-depth-0 " style=" border-radius: 0%; opacity: 1;">
            <i class="material-icons">&#xE2BF;</i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```